# Error: The application encountered the following error: uninitialized constant Suspendable::Boolean (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Error happen on line 5 after upgrading to rails 6.0.0 but couldn't find anything in docs about that.

```
module Suspendable
      extend ActiveSupport::Concern
 
      included do
         field :is_suspended, type: Boolean, default: false
      end
    
      def is_suspended?
        is_suspended
      end
    end
```

Here's the error log

021-05-10T13:18:13.688820+00:00 app[web.1]: App 152 output: Error: The application encountered the following error: uninitialized constant Suspendable::Boolean (NameError)
2021-05-10T13:18:13.689320+00:00 app[web.1]: App 152 output:     /app/app/models/concerns/suspendable.rb:7:in `block in <module:Suspendable>' 2021-05-10T13:18:13.689360+00:00 app[web.1]: App 152 output:     /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/concern.rb:122:in` class_eval'
2021-05-10T13:18:13.689437+00:00 app[web.1]: App 152 output:     /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/concern.rb:122:in `append_features' 2021-05-10T13:18:13.689472+00:00 app[web.1]: App 152 output:     /app/app/models/book.rb:9:in` include'
2021-05-10T13:18:13.689507+00:00 app[web.1]: App 152 output:     /app/app/models/book.rb:9:in `<class:Book>' 2021-05-10T13:18:13.689541+00:00 app[web.1]: App 152 output:     /app/app/models/book.rb:3:in` <top (required)>'
2021-05-10T13:18:13.689833+00:00 app[web.1]: App 152 output:     /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:14:in `block in loading' 2021-05-10T13:18:13.689871+00:00 app[web.1]: App 152 output:     /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:151:in` exclusive'
2021-05-10T13:18:13.689924+00:00 app[web.1]: App 152 output:     /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:13:in `loading' 2021-05-10T13:18:13.689973+00:00 app[web.1]: App 152 output:     /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:480:in` block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2021-05-10T13:18:13.690008+00:00 app[web.1]: App 152 output:     /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `each' 2021-05-10T13:18:13.690042+00:00 app[web.1]: App 152 output:     /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in` block in eager_load!'
2021-05-10T13:18:13.690076+00:00 app[web.1]: App 152 output:     /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:476:in `each' 2021-05-10T13:18:13.690145+00:00 app[web.1]: App 152 output:     /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:476:in` eager_load!'
2021-05-10T13:18:13.690349+00:00 app[web.1]: App 152 output:     /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:356:in `eager_load!' 2021-05-10T13:18:13.690386+00:00 app[web.1]: App 152 output:     /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:123:in` each'
2021-05-10T13:18:13.690421+00:00 app[web.1]: App 152 output:     /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:123:in `block in <module:Finisher>' 2021-05-10T13:18:13.690488+00:00 app[web.1]: App 152 output:     /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in` instance_exec'
2021-05-10T13:18:13.690529+00:00 app[web.1]: App 152 output:     /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run' 2021-05-10T13:18:13.690563+00:00 app[web.1]: App 152 output:     /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in` block in run_initializers'
2021-05-10T13:18:13.690597+00:00 app[web.1]: App 152 output:     /app/vendor/ruby-2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each' 2021-05-10T13:18:13.690646+00:00 app[web.1]: App 152 output:     /app/vendor/ruby-2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:350:in` block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2021-05-10T13:18:13.690695+00:00 app[web.1]: App 152 output:     /app/vendor/ruby-2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from' 2021-05-10T13:18:13.690728+00:00 app[web.1]: App 152 output:     /app/vendor/ruby-2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:349:in` block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2021-05-10T13:18:13.690761+00:00 app[web.1]: App 152 output:     /app/vendor/ruby-2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each' 2021-05-10T13:18:13.690795+00:00 app[web.1]: App 152 output:     /app/vendor/ruby-2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in` call'
2021-05-10T13:18:13.690866+00:00 app[web.1]: App 152 output:     /app/vendor/ruby-2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component' 2021-05-10T13:18:13.690899+00:00 app[web.1]: App 152 output:     /app/vendor/ruby-2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:226:in` tsort_each'
2021-05-10T13:18:13.690932+00:00 app[web.1]: App 152 output:     /app/vendor/ruby-2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each' 2021-05-10T13:18:13.690964+00:00 app[web.1]: App 152 output:     /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in` run_initializers'
2021-05-10T13:18:13.691047+00:00 app[web.1]: App 152 output:     /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:363:in `initialize!' 2021-05-10T13:18:13.691080+00:00 app[web.1]: App 152 output:     /app/config/environment.rb:5:in` <top (required)>'
2021-05-10T13:18:13.691113+00:00 app[web.1]: App 152 output:     config.ru:3:in `require' 2021-05-10T13:18:13.691143+00:00 app[web.1]: App 152 output:     config.ru:3:in` block in '
2021-05-10T13:18:13.691209+00:00 app[web.1]: App 152 output:     /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:125:in `instance_eval' 2021-05-10T13:18:13.691240+00:00 app[web.1]: App 152 output:     /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:125:in` initialize'
2021-05-10T13:18:13.691270+00:00 app[web.1]: App 152 output:     config.ru:1:in `new' 2021-05-10T13:18:13.691298+00:00 app[web.1]: App 152 output:     config.ru:1:in` '
2021-05-10T13:18:13.691344+00:00 app[web.1]: App 152 output:     /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/passenger-6.0.8/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:101:in `eval' 2021-05-10T13:18:13.691388+00:00 app[web.1]: App 152 output:     /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/passenger-6.0.8/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:101:in` preload_app'
2021-05-10T13:18:13.691418+00:00 app[web.1]: App 152 output:     /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/passenger-6.0.8/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:189:in `block in <module:App>' 2021-05-10T13:18:13.691454+00:00 app[web.1]: App 152 output:     /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/passenger-6.0.8/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:390:in` run_block_and_record_step_progress'
2021-05-10T13:18:13.691489+00:00 app[web.1]: App 152 output:     /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/passenger-6.0.8/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:188:in `<module:App>' 2021-05-10T13:18:13.691559+00:00 app[web.1]: App 152 output:     /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/passenger-6.0.8/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in` module:PhusionPassenger'
2021-05-10T13:18:13.691597+00:00 app[web.1]: App 152 output:     /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/passenger-6.0.8/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `'
2021-05-10T13:18:13.905904+00:00 app[web.1]: [ E 2021-05-10 09:18:13.9054 68/Tw age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:221 ]: Could not spawn process for application /app: The application encountered the following error: uninitialized constant Suspendable::Boolean (NameError)
2021-05-10T13:18:13.906953+00:00 app[web.1]: Error ID: 08ac2b12
2021-05-10T13:18:13.907016+00:00 app[web.1]: Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-y0s9rk.html
2021-05-10T13:18:13.907051+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-05-10T13:18:13.924195+00:00 app[web.1]: [ E 2021-05-10 09:18:13.9236 68/Ta age/Cor/Con/CheckoutSession.cpp:276 ]: [Client 2-1] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is 08ac2b12. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.

Comment: @Louis-Bendard Was that working fine with previous version and started raising error after updating to Rails 6 only?

Comment: line field :is_suspended, type: Boolean, default: false... but it in comment make the app starts..

Comment: instead of `Boolean` try `::Boolean`, please let me know if that works.

Comment: @Louis-Bendard any luck with `::Boolean`?

Comment: No louck, got the same error

Comment: Can you please share updated code here.

Comment: I just have the same issue. It only happens in concerns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is still looking for the answer. This can help to workaround

```
included do |base|
  field :is_suspended, type: base::Boolean, default: false
end
```